# Find and replace dynamic values via for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

`http://www.test.com/test.aspx?testinfo=&|&`

I am trying to replace & with values from a table. I got name and age as two paramaters that I need to substitue and get url like this:

`http://www.test.com/test.aspx?testinfo=name|age`

If I have 3 string parameters to be replaced for a url:

`http://www.test.com/test.aspx?testinfo=&|&`

Viz name, age, address for the above url:

`http://www.test.com/test.aspx?testinfo=name|age|address`

```
string URL=string.Empty;
URL=http://www.test.com/test.aspx?testinfo=&|&;
//in this case fieldsCount is 2, ie. name and age
for(int i=0; i<fieldsCount.Length-1;i++)
{
      URL.Replace("*","name");
}
```

How do I add "age" so that I get ? any inputs will be helpful.

`http://www.test.com/test.aspx?testinfo=name|age`

Comment: This post is not very clear. Can you try and edit your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want,

```
    List<string> keys = new List<string>() { "name", "age", "param3" };
    string url = "http://www.test.com/test.aspx?testinfo=&|&;";
    Regex reg = new Regex("&");
    int count = url.Count(p => p == '&');

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (i >= keys.Count)
            break;
        url = reg.Replace(url, keys[i], 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious about two things.

- Why are you using `&` as something to replace, when this has contextual
  meaning within the query string as a delimiter between key/value
  pairs?
- Why does your string have just 2 fields (`&|&`), when sometimes
  the value to replace it with has more than 2 keys?

If these things don't matter, it would make more sense to me to have a replacement string of something else... for instance `http://www.test.com/test.aspx?testinfo=[testinfo]`. Of course, you need to choose something that has 0 chance of showing up in your Url apart from where you expect it. You can then replace it with something like the following:

```
url = url.Replace("[testinfo]", string.Join("|", fieldsCount));
```

Note that this doesn't require your for-loop, and should result in your expected url.
See [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) on msdn.

> Concatenates all the elements of a string array, using the specified
>   separator between each element.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, I think you need something like this:

```
private static string SubstituteAmpersands(string url, string[] substitutes)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int substitutesIndex = 0;

    foreach (char c in url)
    {
        if (c == '&' && substitutesIndex < substitutes.Length)
            result.Append(substitutes[substitutesIndex++]);
        else
            result.Append(c);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```